# Remove html and js file from Filter item display template

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a custom filter and search item Display template in the Master page Gallery. I want to delete them using Code behind before i add the new js files. How to get the master page Gallery library from Code behind ?.

Should i be {sitecollection}/_catalogs/MasterPage or any other way to get the library ?.

Answer (score 0):

The location for Master Page Gallery is `{sitecollection}/_catalogs/MasterPage`. Using this path should be just fine.

Reference: [Map a network drive to the SharePoint Master Page Gallery.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-map-a-network-drive-to-the-sharepoint-master-page-gallery)